# breqn makes sub \theta_{1} partially erased

Tags: breqn, amssymb

The following code with breqn package makes \theta_1 partially erased as in the figure. Is there anyway to keep breqn package and avoid this error? I am using breqn package and these symbols in my project.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,breqn}
\begin{document}
$ \rm O_{\mathfrak{X}} \ \mathfrak{X} \ \mathcal{F}_{m_{\theta_{1}}}   $
\end{document}
```

[image: sub \theta_1 partially erased]

Comment: never use `\rm` in latex, especially not in math and even more so in breqn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\rm` is not defined by default in latex. Some document classes define it for legacy  compatibility with documents from the 1980's, but any effect that has on breqn is accidental.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,breqn}
\begin{document}
$ O_{\mathfrak{X}} \ \mathfrak{X} \ \mathcal{F}_{m_{\theta_{1}}}   $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I replaced \rm with \mathrm.

Comment: @veo note `\mathrm{O}` just applies to O but your `\rm` applied to the whole math expression (which is why theta at the end broke)

Comment: Thank you for your another clarification!